# waypoints infinite scroll did not work

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll, jquery-waypoints

[image: none]

see this image this is an example for what am I trying to do with "Waypoints" Class in JQuery.

But it not goes so well.

Here is the link that show what I tried with the Class.

http://build-net.co.il/waypoints/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what you asked, but I think you could use an `overflow : scroll` with a fixed height on the left div.
I adapted your code so you can see how it looks :

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hL57e/)

But I think the best solution would be to get rid of the

```
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

to make the entire body scrollable, and just set the right div as `position : fixed` like that :

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WyHM4/)

That will also make your divs more easily scallable to the window's size.

But as I don't exactly know why you need this, I let you choose the best solution for what you need.

Hope I helped you.

Comment: Thanks for your try,
But its not what I need.
I dont want the scroll bar, I mean the visitor should not see it same as that: http://www.daba.in.rs/tf/jumper1.5

Comment: I don't understand what you want, I can see the scrollbar on this example... btw if you just wanna hide it you can use `::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }`

Comment: Peraphs our resoulution is not the same..

I want the scroll will work but not shown.
I tried your code, And the scroll bar is still shown.

Comment: Well, you can also try to hide it with absolute positioning, but that's quite a dirty trick... see : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UdcBF/)

Comment: i dont want to use that,
i like to use waypoints infinite plugin in the left div...

Comment: i did not under stand how did you hide the scroll..
can u tell me ?

Comment: Here's another SO question about Waypoints infinite scroll that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845377/continuous-scrolling-with-jquery-waypoints/29158212#comment51715911_29158212